# What is that red hammer icon?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I noticed a red hammer icon when viewing armor or weapons in the inventory. Can anyone explain what it means? What's the meaning of the number next to it?

The following screenshot shows the red hammer icon in the lower left area.

[image: The Witcher 3 inventory with red hammer icon]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**This means that some of your armor parts are (partially) broken and need to be repaired.**

The first number (white, `30`) indicates your armor value. In your case your character's armor would have a value of 30.

The second number (red, `-1`) shows you that your armor is broken and how much you lose of that value. So in your case the broken armor reduces your overall armor by 1, so that you have 29 armor.

This can also happen with just picked-up armor. So even if it's a new one, it can be (partially) broken.

Comment: What does the number indicate? E.g. -1 or -3?

Comment: @Exa this means the item stats are reduced. In your picture the armor value is 30 but because it is partially broken the actual value is 29.

Comment: Added a number explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the Witcher 3 it indicates the equipments condition, as in, it's damaged. It will most probably mean the same in other games

In gaming in general, for a long while now, there are a few *"universal icons"*, one of them is the "hey, your stuff is broken" icon. Usually represented by an icon of the item colored yellow or red, sometimes with a lightning looking gap in them, it can also be a hammer with a yellow or red theme to them ( *hammer usually represents a blacksmith or any other artesian and the coloring is ergency* ). 
so next time you see it you'll know you need to **maintain your stuff**